# How do I stop Chrome from exiting fullscreen on macOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

After updating to macOS Sierra, I've encountered the following bug with Chrome:

1. Have Chrome in fullscreen mode
2. Open up the "Search in page" dropdown `cmd + f`
3. Press escape

Previously, this would close the "search in page" dropdown.  Now, Chrome exits fullscreen.  Pressing escape in other situations does not exit fullscreen.  How can I revert escape back to its previous binding?

Comment: Huh, really sad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Chrome. A workaround, as [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/m8oJSnDpnBc;context-place=forum/chrome) post suggests, is to use `Fn + Esc`.

Comment: According to [this comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=628979#c4) it is a Sierra bug and not a Chrome bug.

Comment: Although later in the ticket the status is fixed (2 days ago) and in Chrome Canary it appears to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug, as stated above. It is fixed in Chrome 55.0.2883.20 and above. The google beta as of this date is 55.0.2883.28, which it's fixed in.

To switch to this version, simply download the Chrome Beta dmg from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html. Once you have it downloaded, close all Chrome applications and "replace" the current version.

I have tested it and it works in "55.0.2883.28 (Beta)", with "macOS 10.12 (16A323)".

I hope this helps anyone that comes across this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not only Chrome bug, but also a bug in apps that use to provide escape fullscreen functionality by pressing Esc. I experience same issues in iTunes and Todoist. `Fn + Esc` solution serves well in Chrome and iTunes, but not in Todoist.